# Getting Error "All formats failed to parse. No formats found"

Tags: r

I got the error when I use dplyr and lubridate package.

```html
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

summary(data)
data %>%
   group_by(yearmonth = format(ymd_hm(Time), "%Y-%m")) %>%
   summarise(Ratio = mean(Emotion == "Positive"))
```

Comment: You should check whether you are using the right function (`ymd_hm`) of the `lubridate` parsing function family. You probably chose the wrong one.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data so we can run the code that's giving you an error

Comment: What's the error?